# How monkey_patch(time=True) affects eventlet.spawn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eventlet, greenlets

Normally, when using greenthread, I can write code as:

```
def myfun():
    print "in my func"
eventlet.spawn(myfunc)
eventlet.sleep(0)  #then myfunc() is triggered as a thread.
```

But after use `money_patch(time=true)`,  I can change the code as:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch(time=True)
eventlet.spawn(myfunc) # now myfunc is called immediately
```

Why I dont need to call `eventlet.sleep(0)` this time?

And after I write my own sleep function:

```
def my_sleep(seconds):
    print "oh, my god, my own..."
```

and set the sleep attr of built-in time module as `my_sleep` func, then I find `my_sleep` func would be called so many times with a lot of outputs.
But I can only see only one debug-thread in eclipse, which did not call `my_sleep` func.

So, the conclusion is, sleep function is called continually by default, and I think that the authors of eventlet know this, so they developed the `monkey_patch()` function. Is that rigth?

#

According the answer of @temoto, CPython cannot reproduce the same result. I thinks I should add some message to introduce how I find this interesting thing.(Why I did not add this message at first time, cause input so many words in not easy, and my English is not that good.^^)

I find this thing when I remote-debug openstack code using eclipse.

In nova/network/model.py, a function is written like this:

```
class NetworkInfoAsyncWrapper(NetworkInfo):
    """Wrapper around NetworkInfo that allows retrieving NetworkInfo
    in an async manner.

    This allows one to start querying for network information before
    you know you will need it.  If you have a long-running
    operation, this allows the network model retrieval to occur in the
    background.  When you need the data, it will ensure the async
    operation has completed.

    As an example:

    def allocate_net_info(arg1, arg2)
        return call_neutron_to_allocate(arg1, arg2)

    network_info = NetworkInfoAsyncWrapper(allocate_net_info, arg1, arg2)
    [do a long running operation -- real network_info will be retrieved
    in the background]
    [do something with network_info]
    """

    def __init__(self, async_method, *args, **kwargs):
        self._gt = eventlet.spawn(async_method, *args, **kwargs)
        methods = ['json', 'fixed_ips', 'floating_ips']
        for method in methods:
            fn = getattr(self, method)
            wrapper = functools.partial(self._sync_wrapper, fn)
            functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, fn)
            setattr(self, method, wrapper)
```

When I first debug to this function, After exeute

> self._gt = eventlet.spawn(async_method, *args, **kwargs)

the call-back function `async_method` is exeuted at once. But please remember, this is a thread, it should be triggered by `eventlet.sleep(0)`.

But I didnt find the code to call `sleep(0)`, so if `sleep` is perhaps called by eclipse, then in the real world(not-debug world), who triggered it?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Eventlet API does not require `sleep(0)` to start a green thread. `spawn(fun)` will start function some time in future, including right now. You only should call `sleep(0)` to *ensure* that it starts right now, and even then it's better to use explicit synchronization, like `Event` or `Semaphore`.

I can't reproduce this behavior using CPython 2.7.6 and 3.4.3, eventlet 0.17.4 in either IPython or pure python console. So it's probably Eclipse who is calling `time.sleep` in background.

`monkey_patch` was introduced as a shortcut to running through all your (and third party) code and replacing `time.sleep -> eventlet.sleep`, and similar for `os`, `socket`, etc modules. It's not related to Eclipse (or something else) repeating `time.sleep` calls.

But this is an interesting observation, thank you.

Comment: I added some content in the answer. :-)